# How to grant access to individual certificate in Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-rbac

I have created an Azure Keyvault. I have added a certificate and private key to the Keyvault. The keyvault is using Role Based Access Controls.

I have an Azure AD user account I am trying to grant access to read the private key.

I have granted the following permissions at the vault level to the user:

- Key Vault Reader
- Reader

I have granted the following permissions on the individual certificate:

- Key Vault Certificate User

The request fails with permission denied. However, if I add the `Key Vault Certificate User` role at the vault level, the request succeeds.

The documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/rbac-guide?tabs=azure-cli) clearly states:

- `Key Vault Certificate User` - Read entire certificate contents including secret and key portion. Only works for key vaults that use the 'Azure role-based access control' permission model.
- **Best Practices for individual keys, secrets, and certificates role assignments** - Individual keys, secrets, and certificates permissions should be used only for specific scenarios: Sharing individual secrets between multiple applications, for example, one application needs to access data from the other application

So, not only is it confirmed `Key Vault Certificate User` is the proper permission to access the cert. They also indicate that individual permissions on the certificate is possible, despite it not being a best practice.

**Why when I assign the permission at the cert level I cannot access the private key, but when assigned at the vault level it works fine?**

Answer (score 0):

Initially I assigned Key Vault Reader role and reader role to the user at the vault level and Key Vault Certificate User to the user:

[image]

Now when I tried to download the private key of the certificate referring to this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/how-to-export-certificate?tabs=azure-cli#export-stored-certificates) I got the **error** ***"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource"*:**

```bash
az login

az keyvault secret download --id https://rukkv3394.vault.azure.net/secrets/rukkpfx --file "C:\Users\rukmini\Desktop\certificate.pfx"
```

[image]

Hence as a **workaround**, I tried to assign the user Key Vault Certificate User to the user by passing the correct scope of the certificate:

```bash
az role assignment create --role "Key Vault Certificate User" --assignee kvrukuser@xxx.onmicrosoft.com --scope /subscriptions/SubID/resourcegroups/RGName/providers/microsoft.keyvault/vaults/KeyVaultName/secrets/CertificateName
```

[image]

Now when **I tried to download the certificate private key and public metadata**, its successful like below:

```bash
az keyvault secret download --id https://rukkv3394.vault.azure.net/secrets/rukkpfx --file "C:\Users\rukmini\Desktop\certificate.pfx"
```

[image]

[image]

***To verify**, I created one more certificate in the Key Vault and dint add role to the user for this certificate:*

[image]

When I tried to download the certificate, I got the error ***"Caller is not authorized to perform action on resource"*** like below:

[image]

By using the above workaround, you can grant access to individual certificate in Azure Key Vault.

Comment: Ok, I will give this a shot. But, to be clear, it appears the suggestion is to use the CLI to assign the permissions while specifying a scope to the individual cert. How is this different than assigning it in the GUI as you first tried? Or perhaps the better question, "is there a GUI equivalent to this?"

Comment: Please try doing it from CLI and let me know if it works